# Chrome Javascript issue with table rows

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

This works in IE but not Chrome. So something to do with how the browser handles the code. I'm fairly new to all this so apologies for not realizing the solution if it's simple. I looked around for something similar but couldn't find it.

```
function reFillTable(newData)
{
var tbl = document.getElementById("string"); //works
var tblLength = tbl.rows.length; //this works fine
var row = null;
var cell = null;
splitString = newData.split(" ");
var tableIndex = 1;

for (var n = 0; n < tblLength; n++)
{

  row = tbl.rows(n); //this breaks in chrome but not IE???????
  //code continues but is irrelevant as of now...

}



}
```

I can get an alert before the "row = tbl.rows(n);" but not after so it's clearly breaking on this line. What's the deal here? Also, is there a better way to traverse a table than this method? It was the only thing I found so I've been using this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `row = tbl.rows[n];`

It is the proper way for traversing table, and supported by all browsers

Comment: Ok, so yea, when I first learned how to traverse a table, the guide didn't explain that it was an array. Hate how javascript is just "var" everything and your left to know if it's a String/int/array/whatever.

Comment: javascript is a wonderful language, if u have the patience to learn it

Comment: I suppose, I'm just starting on programming and learned Java first. Everything is nice and direct. You know if your dealing with arrays/strings/etc... So I'm just not used to having to deal with these kinds of issues. I'm sure I'll come to like it once I learn it better.

Answer (score 1):

Rows returns an array so change `tbl.rows(n)` to `tbl.rows[n]`.  [Full details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/table.rows) on MDN.